# Installation media can't be found in windows 10 installation tool

Tags: windows, boot

I wanted to reinstall windows 10 but at first, decided to convert my disk from MBR to GPT. I did it with command prompt in recovery mode and then changed BIOS from Legacy to UEFI. then I realized that my disk wasn't wiped out and windows 10 loaded up perfectly. but I still wanted to reinstall windows 10 so I used a GPT booted USB containing windows 10 but in the installation part, I got "can't find missing media for installing media, please insert USB or DVD that contains installing media" Error. please help me to solve this problem and reinstall windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> then I realized that my disk wasn't wiped out and windows 10 loaded up
> perfectly. but I still wanted to reinstall windows 10

Since Windows is running, use the Windows 10 Repair Function and Keep Nothing.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed.

At the point where the Repair asks for what to keep,  uncheck both Apps and Data, so Keep Nothing.

You will get a brand new installation including a new User Profile and Account.

This is the easiest way forward for you. I have done this and it works fine.